# Type 'IconType' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

have been looking for a way to properly render an icon in my component but ended up with an error from the title.

`Profile.tsx:`

```
<ul>
  {socialLinks.map((socialLink) => (
    <li key={socialLink.href}>
      <a href={socialLink.href}>{socialLink.icon}</a>
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

`data.ts`

```
import { FaDiscord, FaGithub, FaTwitter } from "react-icons/fa";

export const socialLinks = [
  {
    name: "github",
    href: "#",
    icon: FaGithub,
  },
  {
    name: "twitter",
    href: "#",
    icon: FaTwitter,
  },
  {
    name: "discord",
    href: "#",
    icon: FaDiscord,
  },
];
```

is there a way to fix this?

Comment: We are missing the essential code. Where are those icons used? Or where does this error appear?

Comment: The icons are used in `Profile.tsx` file while iterating through the array of social links from `data.ts`. Error appears in the same file, where they are used. Didn't understand your words about essential code. I think everything is pretty much visible here. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `icon` is a *functional component*. You have to invoke it.

Either, invoke it directly in the data config:

```
{ icon: <FaGithub />, name: ..., href: ... }
```

or when mapping:

```
{socialLinks.map((socialLink) => {
   const Icon = socialLink.icon;

   return (
     <li key={socialLink.href}>
       <a href={socialLink.href}>
         <Icon />
       </a>
    </li>
   );
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reassign the `socialLinks.icon` to a new variable and then render it as a React component in the tsx file. I believe the following should work:

```js
<ul>
  {socialLinks.map((socialLink) => {
    const Icon = socialLink.icon
    return (
      <li key={socialLink.href}>
        <a href={socialLink.href}><Icon/></a>
      </li>
  ))}}
</ul>
```

Comment: Replied to you yesterday, however I don't see my comment now. Much grateful for your answer, this one works as well.